# searching and retrieving set elements containing partial string when set is large

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, search, set

I am working on a large dataset ~1 billion lines. I have them as a `set`.

My task is to pick out those lines that contain the work `'risk'`.

So, I used

```
a = [sent for sent in sent_set if 'risk' in sent]
```

Is there a better, faster (more pythonic) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an example here that uses numbers instead of text, since that is easier for me to demonstrate.

```
import time

mySet = set(range(1000000))

clock = time.perf_counter()
a = [x for x in mySet if x % 5 == 3] 
print(time.perf_counter() - clock)

clock = time.perf_counter()
b = list(filter(lambda x: x % 5 == 3, mySet))
print(time.perf_counter() - clock)

clock = time.perf_counter()
c = filter(lambda x: x % 5 == 3, mySet)
print(time.perf_counter() - clock)
```

```
0.09295209999999998
0.14730990000000002
3.400000000042258e-06
```

Your way of doing it with the list comprehension seems to be perfectly fine, and in fact, is even faster than using `list` and [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). If, however, you are able to work with a generator rather than a full list of the filtered values, then `filter` by itself is much faster than the alternatives.